# Как в canvas нарисовать прямоугольник описанный в xml

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-xml

В Xml описал прямоугольник с градиентом и всё такое, хочу нарисовать его на канве. Возможно ли это ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае:

```
Drawable shape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_shape);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( shape.getIntrinsicWidth(), shape.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888 );
Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
shape.setBounds( 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() );
shape.draw( canvas );
```

В кастомном View:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Drawable shape = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_shape);
    shape.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    shape.draw(canvas)
}
```

где *some_shape* - фигура, заданная через XML

**UPDATE**: Метод класса `Resources` - `getDrawable(int id)` объявлен устаревшим с API 22, вместо него предлагается использовать метод [`getDrawable(int id, Resources.Theme theme)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)). Если ваше приложение имеет минимальный API >= 22, то вы можете использовать предложенный на замену метод, иначе не стоит обращать  внимания на статус *deprecated*

поле *context* во втором примере передается в любой класс-наследник `View` через обязательный конструктор для View-класса.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только у меня не было context , но нашелся GetContext(). и метод getDrawable деприкейтед . Раз так значит велика вероятность, что  есть какая то альтернатива

Comment: pavlofff, я правильно понимаю, что если API ниже 22 , то у них новый метод работать не будет?  и если я хочу использовать новый метод , но диапазон API,допустим от 14 до 25 , то мне стоит реализовать конструкцию Try{} Exption{} , ну или вставить проверку версии API ?

Comment: @Turalllb да, правильно, нужно организовать проверку на версию API, если вы хотите использовать новый метод в приложениях с API<22